# If I do not open an Excel file with web query will it still update automatically or not?

Tags: excel, excel-web-query

I have created a web query on a spreadsheet, will it update automatically if I do not open it?

And does anyone know if Excel on Mac have automatic 1 minute refresh option or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the update without Excel being open, the answer is no: Excel (files) will only update when they are open in Excel, as it is the Excel application that is taking care of the update.

Regarding the automatic update every minute: In the Windows version of Excel this is possible in the properties of the Connection, where you can set the Refresh interval.

Not having Excel 2011, I cannot help. However, checking the properties dialogs shown in [this post](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/excel-2011-mysql-config/), it does not look like there is such an option in Excel 2011.